# Clases en Python e imprimir en distintas líneas

Tags: python, string, class, print

¿cómo andan? Estoy con un ejercicio que lo tengo casi completo, pero me falta una pequeña parte. El ejercicio es el siguiente:

```
Ejercicio 14.9.7. Crear las clases Materia y Carrera, que se comporten según el siguiente ejemplo:
>>> analisis2 = Materia("61.03", "Análisis 2", 8)
>>> fisica2 = Materia("62.01", "Física 2", 8)
>>> algo1 = Materia("75.40", "Algoritmos 1", 6)
>>> c = Carrera([analisis2, fisica2, algo1])
>>> str(c)
Créditos: 0 -- Promedio: N/A -- Materias aprobadas:
>>> c.aprobar("95.14", 7)
ValueError: La materia 75.14 no es parte del plan de estudios
>>> c.aprobar("75.40", 10)
>>> c.aprobar("62.01", 7)
>>> str(c)
Créditos: 14 -- Promedio: 8.5 -- Materias aprobadas:
75.40 Algoritmos 1 (10)
62.01 Física 2 (7)
```

Si no entiendo mal lo que hay que hacer, la clase Materia solamente tomará los valores que reciba. Y la clase Carrera, además, deberá contar con un método aprobar que funcione así:

- Si el código no es parte de la carrera, devolverá el error indicado.
- Si lo es, sumará la cantidad de créditos, obtendrá el promedio e imprimirá nombre y código de las materias aprobadas.
  y un método str que imprimirá 'Créditos: 14 -- Promedio: 8.5 -- Materias aprobadas:' (con los valores correspondientes).

El código que yo usé es el siguiente:

```
class Materia:

    def __init__(self, codigo, nombre, credito):
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.credito = credito

    def get_credito(self):
        return self.credito

    def get_nombre(self):
        return self.nombre

    def get_codigo(self):
        return self.codigo


class Carrera:
    creditos = 0
    aprobadas = 0
    nota_acumulada = 0
    promedio = 0
    lista_materias = []

    def __init__(self, materias):
        self.materias = materias    # materias es una lista
        for i in self.materias:
            Carrera.lista_materias.append(i.get_codigo())
    
    def aprobar(self, codigo, nota):
        try:
            Carrera.lista_materias.index(codigo)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"La materia {codigo} no es parte del plan de estudio.")

        for i in self.materias:
            if codigo == i.get_codigo():
                Carrera.creditos += int(i.get_credito())
                Carrera.nota_acumulada += nota
                Carrera.aprobadas += 1
                Carrera.promedio = Carrera.nota_acumulada / Carrera.aprobadas

    def __str__(self):
        if Carrera.creditos == 0:
            return "Créditos: 0 -- Promedio: N/A -- Materias aprobadas:"
        else:
            return f"Créditos: {Carrera.creditos} -- Promedio: {Carrera.promedio} -- Materias aprobadas:\n"
```

El código cumple bastante bien lo pedido, aunque tiene algunos detalles. Sin embargo, el que más me preocupa por el momento es el método str. No sé cómo hacer para que el código y nombre de la materia aprobada figure en un renglón separado. Sé que se puede usar '\n' para finalizar una línea (como escribo al final del código), pero no como hacer para que cada materia salga en una línea distinta.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Una aclaración ahora que veo el ejercicio. Las impresiones (por ejemplo, 'ValueError: La materia 75.14 no es parte del plan de estudios') deben ser string y en el enunciado parece una mezcla de str con int. El resto sigue igual.

Comment: El string "linea 1\nlinea2" contiene dos líneas. Puedes insertar un `\n` en cualquier parte de la cadena y ahi se producira una nueva línea.

Comment: @CandidMoe pero cómo hago para que en cada línea figure una nueva materia, con su respectivo código y nombre (solamente las aprobadas)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La lógica de este código me parece un poco extraña, así que le hice algunas adaptaciones para mejorar el manejo del indexado de los objetos dentro de la clase.

Sucede que cada materia es un objeto, con sus atributos `codigo`, `nombre` y `credito`. Sin embargo la principal entidad para indexar a una materia, es `codigo`, por lo tanto modifiqué el atributo `materias` para que fuera un diccionario con la forma:

```
self.materias = {'codigo1':obj_materia1, 'codigo2':obj_materia2, ...}
```

Como las notas no las estás almacenando en ningún lado, cree otro atributo (diccionario) que guarda los códigos de las materias ya aprobadas junto con su nota.

```
lista_aprobadas = {'codigo_aprob1':nota1, 'codigo_aprob2':nota2, ...}
```

Los atributos que declaras en la clase `Carrera` no tienen que ser atributos de clase. Pueden ser de instancia, los puse dentro del `__init__()`. Adicional, no es necesario hacer referencia a la clase (`Carrera.xxx`) dentro de su propia clase, para eso es `self`.

Finalmente con los datos guardados e indexados correctamente, se pueden retornar desde el método especial `__str__`

```
class Carrera:
    def __init__(self, materias):
        self.creditos = 0
        self.aprobadas = 0
        self.nota_acumulada = 0
        self.promedio = 0
        self.lista_aprobadas = {}
        self.materias = {}
        for obj in materias:
            self.materias[obj.get_codigo()] = obj
    
    def aprobar(self, codigo, nota):
        if codigo in self.lista_aprobadas:
            print(f"Esta materia ya fue aprobada anteriormente")
        elif codigo in self.materias:
            obj = self.materias[codigo]
            self.creditos += obj.get_credito()
            self.nota_acumulada += nota
            self.aprobadas += 1
            self.promedio = self.nota_acumulada / self.aprobadas
            self.lista_aprobadas[codigo] = nota
        else:
            print(f"La materia {codigo} no es parte del plan de estudio.")

    def __str__(self):
        if self.creditos == 0:
            msg = "Créditos: 0 -- Promedio: N/A -- No tiene materias aprobadas"
        else:
            msg = f"Créditos: {self.creditos} -- Promedio: {self.promedio} -- Materias aprobadas:"
            for cod, nota in self.lista_aprobadas.items():
                msg = f'{msg}\n{cod} {self.materias[cod].get_nombre()} ({nota})'
        return msg
```

Comment: Espectacular. Me imaginé que la lógica en el código iba a tener algunas rarezas. Recién empiezo a trabajar con clases y era muy posible que eso pasara. Te agradezco la respuesta.

Comment: PD: lo de no almacenar las notas de debe a que me había olvidado que era necesario incluirlo en el mensaje final. Si no fuera necesario, ¿es recomendable almacenarlas en algún lado? o ¿se puede dejar así?

Comment: Se puede dejar así. Otra cosa que no puse es que en Python, a menos que sea estrictamente necesario, casi no se usan *setters* y *getters* debido a la naturaleza no encapsulada de las clases. En pocas palabras, puedes quitar los llamados a métodos `.get_codigo()`, `.get_nombre()` y `.get_credito()` y poner el atributo directamente: `.codigo`, `.nombre` y `.credito` y el código funcionará igual.

Comment: el video que había visto explicaba que el prefería hacer esos métodos, aunque no entendía el por qué (es decir, por qué no usaba directamente .credito, etc.). Ahora me quedo más tranquilo sabiendo que no es necesario. Gracias.